# Symfony - Downgrade Minor Version

Tags: symfony

I'm working with a copy of Symfony (2.8.9) which works perfectly on my development server.

I've cloned the same repository that this server pulls from, down to my local, and updated composer / ran the Symfony installer. I started getting an error:

> You have requested a synthetic service ("request").

I did a little research, and found that this is a bug in the next version of Symfony, 2.8.10, as reported here:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19840

I will await the bug being fixed in 2.8.10, but in the meantime, I'd love to be able to downgrade from 2.8.10 to 2.8.9, so my local copy runs and matches the copy on my development server.

I've seen posts regarding changing the version numbers in composer.json, but all my numbers related to Symfony say "2.8", with the minor version number excluded. Additionally, my composer.json file matches on both my dev server and local.

Should I add the minor version number ".9" to the end of the composer.json dependencies, and install the dependencies with composer? Is it enough to add the minor version number to only Symfony-related dependencies, and have all other dependencies work correctly, or are there other version numbers that should be changed as well? Is my approach correct, or is there another way to do this entirely?

Comment: or you can force the version `"symfony/symfony": "2.8.9"` indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit just one line in your `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*, !=2.8.10",
    ...
```

This way, you tell Composer to avoid that specific version. All other dependencies will be retrieved automatically.

Important: you have to remove your `composer.lock` file first, as Composer will complain that you're locked to the very same version you're trying to avoid.

**Disclaimer**: backup and test first. I tested on a base Symfony install, not sure if other package will complain.